# Facebook Graph Explorer giving different results than Graph API request with same permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm writing a script that will pull images that have been posted to an Event's wall and display them in a gallery.

In the Graph Explorer, my Access Token says it covers the following permissions:

```
create_note 
photo_upload
publish_actions 
publish_stream 
read_stream 
share_item 
status_update
user_photos 
video_upload
```

I get all of the pictures when I run the call in the Explorer (https://graph.facebook.com/412742725455517/photos). When I run the same call in my code, using an access token generated by calling:

```
var dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?"
          + "client_id=" + app_id 
          + "&redirect_uri=" + encodeURIComponent(post_login_url)
          + '&response_type=token'
          + "&scope=create_note,photo_upload,publish_actions,publish_stream,read_stream,share_item,status_update,user_photos,video_upload";
```

I get only two of the pictures (the ones placed by the Event Host).

Why can't I get all of the images? Is there an alternate way to get the images?

Comment: The Access Token Debugger says that they both have the same permissions, as well.

Comment: Different migration options between that app and yours?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this fixed the problem, but things coincidentally started working after I did it.

I went into the App settings and set permissions for the app, as well as setting domains for the app (the domains won't save unless you choose "for Website login" even if you aren't using Facebook for website logon). After making these changes, things started working. I don't know why they were relevant.