# Issue retrieving place category in nested graph call

Tags: facebook-graph-api, nested

I am trying to do a nested graph call which will return the category of places for both checkins and locations.

To distill my issue down to the part of the query that doesn't work, I'll use the endpoint `GET /me?fields=locations.fields(place.fields(name,location,category),id)`.

If I run this endpoint with the Graph Browser API Token, I'll receive proper results. However, if I use my actual app's Token, I get

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#100) Unknown fields: category.", 
        "type": "OAuthException", 
        "code": 100
     }
}
```

The place.category field also works fine for checkins with either API token.

I've attempted to resolve this by doing a batch query and using `GET ?ids={result=user-info:$.locations.data.*.place.id}&fields=(name,location)` for the second query, but I receive the same error.

Is this an issue that needs to be resolved on Facebook's end, or is there another way I can execute this query without needing to do n additional requests?

Thanks!

Comment: Are there different permissions in place between your app and the token you're using with the Graph API explorer?

Comment: No, I tried various combinations of permissions on both apps, but as it stands the issue arises even when every permission is selected

Comment: Also, this issue doesn't come up for every user, so I'm wondering whether or not it could have to do with my account settings / a friend's account settings / something to do with a specific location?

Comment: Hi..Some more info would be helpful here. Can you share some posts that we can check to verify this repros ? Not related, but there was a related comment here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/12783006/1628782.

Comment: I just tried following the steps from that other comment, but no luck there. What do you mean by posts you can check? Like results of an actual POST request?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, what I meant was - any examples of the calls that are working via graph api (or explorer); but not working via the actual app access token. I would recommend passing along the info via your FB contact, so that you don't post private data here.

Comment: Yeah, I'll let him know to pass it on to you, thanks!